# sql select all record for all

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, subquery

so there is 3 tables

1 passanger detail

2 booking

3 flight

passanger

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
+----+------+
```

booking

```
+----+-------+
| id |flight |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   101 |
|  1 |   102 |
|  1 |   103 |
|  2 |   101 |
|  3 |   104 |
|  2 |   105 |
+----+-------+
```

flight

```
+--------+------+
| flight | late |
+--------+------+
|    101 |   80 |
|    102 |   80 |
|    103 |   80 |
|    104 |   10 |
|    105 |   10 |
+--------+------+
```

table 1 contains passnger id and name

table 2 contains passanger id and its flight id

table 3 contains flight id and how much minute it is late

now i want to find out name of the passanger whose all flights are 50 minutes late or more

so the output will be `A` because 101 102 and 103 are late by 80 min

**not `B` because 101 is 80 mins late but 105 is 10 mins late (not all of b's flights are late by 50)**

so my approach is

```
select name from passanger,booking where passanger.id=booking.id and booking.flight = ALL (select flight.flight from flight where flight.late>50)
```

can't get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by name and check if all the flights of a passenger are late with a `having` condition.

```
select p.name 
from passanger p
join booking b on p.id=b.id
join flight f on f.flight = b.flight 
group by p.name
having count(*) = count(case when f.late>50 then f.flight end)
```

Comment: please explain this line ** having count(*) = count(case when f.late>50 then f.flight end) **

Comment: for instance, for passenger id 2, there are 2 rows..i.e count(*) =2, and `count(case when f.late>50 then f.flight end)` would be 1 because only one of his flights is >50 late, the other row fails the condition and wouldn't be counted. so the condition fails as (2!=1). similarly for passenger id 1, count(*) = 3 and `count(case when f.late>50 then f.flight end)` = 3. so you would get that row in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select name from passanger, booking
where passanger.id = booking.id 
and booking.flight in (select flight.flight from flight 
                       where flight.late > 50)
```

or

```
select name from passanger, booking, flight
where passanger.id = booking.id and booking.flight = flight.flight and flight.late > 50
```

This will result in a's name 3 times and b's name once but if you want to get only one instance of a and b in the result, you can use `select distinct name`.

Comment: `booking` table is missed from  `FROM`

Comment: i added that but later accidentally deleted it while editing to indent properly, thanks for pointing that :d

Answer (score 0):

```
 select ps.name from passanger ps left join booking bk on (ps.id = bk.id) left join flight fl on (fl.flight = bk.flight) where  late >50
```